# Does exist another models like CARDIAC, LMC and IPC?

Tags: computer-architecture, programming-languages, pedagogy

I'm working with *CARDIAC* (Cardboard Illustrative Aid to Computation) that is a model created at Bell Labs in 1968 to explain students how the computers worked with the Von Neumann architecture to *create a new model for pedagogical purpose*. But, I couldn't find an extension to parallel and concurrent computation, because the original model doesn't have the enough hardware to do it, so I'm creating an extension for this two concepts based on the original CARDIAC.

In this process I've been looking for other models that were created to the same purpose, I found MARIE(Machine Architecture that is Really Intuitive and Easy), TIMBA(Terrible Imbecile Machine for Boring Algorithms), Ant-32, VSCPU, OAMulator, and the classics Little Man Computer(LMC) and Instructo Paper Computer(IPC). But none of these have the enough characteristics to explain concurrent and parallel computation and at the same time will have the easily that has CARDIAC for a new student.

So, do you know any other that I couldn't find? I don't want to ignore some previous work

Comment: Looks a perfect [topic for CS Educators@SE](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).